# How to build json dynamically from formidable

Tags: node.js, json, formidable

Am trying to build a json object from request's form fields dynamically, the fields are recevied okey, but I can't get the json to be built as I want.

I tried the below approach

```
let userJson = {}

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req);

form.on('field', function (name, value) {
   userJson[name]=value; //didn't work
   [userJson.name]=value]; // didn't work
});
```

Comment: Which version of formiddable are you using?

Comment: Am using version `1.2.1`

Comment: Thanks, did you try to use the callback of the parse function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it manually in two steps ...

```
var userJson = []

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('field', function (name, value) {
        userJson.push('"' + name + '"' + ':' + '"' + value + '"')
    });
```

and then I did

```
form.on('end', function (name, file) {
        userJson = '{' + userJson.toString() + '}'
        userJson = JSON.parse(userJson)
        console.log(userJson)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the parse method, you don't need to build a json variable, its callback already retrieves you one, like so:

```
let userJson = {};

const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, (err, fields) => {
    userJson = {...fields};
    // do whatever you want afterwards
});
```

Hope to have helped!

Comment: not working because instead of {key: value} you get {key: [value]}

Answer (score 0):

Exorcismus' method would not work if any of the keys or values contain double quotes and could lead to security vulnerabilities in certain situations (such as circumventing field validations).

Here's a safer way if I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly:

```js
var userJson = {};

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req);
form.on('field', function (name, value) {
    userJson[name] = value;
});
```